# Function used to define whether a number is prime or not causes c++ program to crash

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have been trying to create this program for several hours and have gotten to the point where i am completely stumped. I am using the GNU GCC Compiler in codeblocks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool Is_Prime(int number);

int main() {
    if (Is_Prime(3)) {
        cout << "Prime" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
bool Is_Prime(int number) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        if ((number % i) == 0) {
            x = x + 1;
        }
        if (x > 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

it's probably something stupid but i am only new to programming

Comment: The modulo operator `%` is a doing a *division*, and division with zero is...?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll quickly edit my version of the code and see if it works

Comment: It Worked :D Thank You for your help

Comment: Per the C++ standard, §5.6/4, "If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined;" - so, there you go.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: @JakeWickham How old are you? Where are your parents? Did you read about the policies for asking questions at this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The fix is to start your loop from `1`, not from `0`:

```
...
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
...
```

Also, you don't need to check all the numbers from `1` to `number` to make sure `number` is prime. As soon the first divisor have found, you can be sure `number` is not prime. And if no divisors were found from `1` to `sqrt(number)`, you can be sure `number` is prime. And there's also a special case of `1`.

So, let me enhance your code a bit:

```
bool Is_Prime(int number)
{
  for (int i = 2; i * i <= number; ++i)
  {
    if (number % i == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return number > 1;
}
```

*UP*: Also, if you expect that your program may be executed for numbers which are close to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, then line `i * i` may overflow. In this case you may use less readable, but safer alternative:

```
i <= number / i
```

Comment: (this comment is wrong) `number % 1` will always be zero, so this won't make the program correct.

Comment: Ah, I understood what the program means and my previous comment is incorrect.

Comment: Plus one for `i * i <= number` alone.

Answer (score 0):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using 0 as the second operand of `%` operator ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.6 Multiplicative operators, paragraph 4), and it seems made the program crash. You should start iterating from 1, not 0.

Another note is that integer which are 1 or less are not prime, so they should be rejected before the loop.